# Remove Base64 prefix from InputStream

Tags: java, stream, base64, inputstream, fresco

I have a Base64 encoded Image String residing in a File Server. The encoded String has a [prefix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) (ex: "data:image/png;base64,") for support in popular modern browsers (it's obtained via JavaScript's [Canvas.toDataURL() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)). The client sends a request for the image to my server which verifies them and returns a stream of the Base64 encoded String.

If the client is a web client, the image can be displayed as is within an `<img>` tag by setting the `src` to the Base64 encoded String. However, if the client is an Android client, the String needs to be decoded into a Bitmap without the prefix. Though, this can be done fairly easily.

**The Problem:**
In order to simplify my code and not reinvent the wheel, I'm using an Image Library for the Android client to handle loading, displaying, and caching the images (Facebook's [Fresco Library](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) to be exact). However, no library seems to support Base64 decoding (I want my cake and to eat it too). A solution I came up with is to decode the Base64 String on the server as it is being streamed to the client.

**The Attempt:**

```
S3Object obj = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName));
Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
//decodes the stream as it is being read
InputStream stream = decoder.wrap(obj.getObjectContent());
try{
    return new StreamingOutput(){
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException{
            int nextByte = 0;
            while((nextByte = stream.read()) != -1){
                output.write(nextByte);
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            stream.close();
        }
    };
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Unfortunately, the Fresco library still has a problem displaying the image (with no stack traces!). As there doesn't seem to be an issue on my server when decoding the stream (no stack traces either), it leads me to believe that it must be an issue with the prefix. Which leaves me with a dilemma.

**The Question:** How do I remove the Base64 prefix from a Stream being sent to the client without storing and editing the entire Stream on the server? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I remove the Base64 prefix from a Stream being sent to the client without storing and editing the entire Stream on the server?

Removing the prefix while sending the stream to the client turns out to be a pretty complex task. If you don't mind storing the whole String on the server you could simply do:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    String result = sb.toString();
    //comma is the charater which seperates the prefix and the Base64 String
    int i = result.indexOf(",");
    result = result.substring(i + 1);
    //Now, that we have just the Base64 encoded String, we can decode it
    Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
    byte[] decoded = decoder.decode(result);
    //Now, just write each byte from the byte array to the output stream
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But to be more efficient and not store the entire Stream on the server, creates a much more complicated task. We could use the [Base64.Decoder.wrap() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap-java.io.InputStream-) but the problem with that is that it throws an IOException if it reaches a value that cannot be decoded (wouldn't it be nice if they provided a method that just left the bytes as is if they can't be decoded?). And unfortunately, the Base64 prefix can't be decoded because it's not Base64 encoded. So, it would throw an IOException.

To get around this problem, we would have to use an `InputStreamReader` to read the `InputStream` with the specified appropriate `Charset`. Then we would have to cast the `int`s received from the InputStream's read() method call to `char`s. When we reach the appropriate amount of chars, we would have to compare it with the Base64 prefix's intro ("data"). If it's a match, we know the Stream contains the prefix, so continue reading until we reach the prefix end character (the comma: ","). Finally, we can begin streaming out the bytes after the prefix. Example:

```
S3Object obj = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName));
Base64.Decoder decoder = Base64.getDecoder();
InputStream stream = obj.getObjectContent();
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
try{
    return new StreamingOutput(){
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException{
            //for checking if string has base64 prefix
            char[] pre = new char[4]; //"data" has at most four bytes on a UTF-8 encoding
            boolean containsPre = false;
            int count = 0;
            int nextByte = 0;
            while((nextByte = stream.read()) != -1){
                if(count < pre.length){
                    pre[count] = (char) nextByte;
                    count++;
                }else if(count == pre.length){
                    //determine whether has prefix or not and act accordingly
                    count++;
                    containsPre = (Arrays.toString(pre).toLowerCase().equals("data")) ? true : false;
                    if(!containsPre){
                        //doesn't have Base64 prefix so write all the bytes until this point
                        for(int i = 0; i < pre.length; i++){
                            output.write((int) pre[i]);
                        }
                        output.write(nextByte);
                    }
                }else if(containsPre && count < 25){
                    //the comma character (,) is considered the end of the Base64 prefix
                    //so look for the comma, but be realistic, if we don't find it at about 25 characters
                    //we can assume the String is not encoded correctly
                    containsPre = (Character.toString((char) nextByte).equals(",")) ? false : true;
                    count++;
                }else{
                    output.write(nextByte);
                }
            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            stream.close();
        }
    };
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
```

This seems a bit hefty of a task to do on the server so I think decoding on the client side is a better choice. Unfortunately, most Android client side libraries don't have support for Base64 decoding (especially with the prefix). However, as @tyronen pointed out [Fresco does support it](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/demo/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/demo/MainActivity.java#L99) if the String is already obtained. Though, this removes one of the key reasons to use an **image loading** library.

**Android Client Side Decoding**

To decode on the client side application is pretty easy. First obtain the String from the InputStream:

```
BufferedReader br = null;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    return sb.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Then decode the String using Android's Base64 class:

```
int i = result.indexOf(",");
result = result.substring(i + 1);
byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(result, Base64.DEFAULT);
Bitmap bitMap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
```

The Fresco library seems hard to update due to them using a lot of delegation. So, I moved on to using the Picasso image loading library and created my [own fork of it](https://github.com/chRyNaN/picasso) with the Base64 decoding ability.

Answer (score 0):

Fresco does support decoding data URIs, just as the web client does.

The demo app has an [example](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/demo/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/demo/MainActivity.java#L99) of this.

Comment: Unfortunately, the example assumes the Base64 encoded String is already available on the device. Since it is retrieved from the server, I would have to make a request, parse the response to Uri, and then set to the SimpleDraweeView. Which removes one of the key components of the library, "[Fresco] takes care of **image loading** and displaying so you don't have to." [1](http://frescolib.org/)